# $p+1$ is divisible by $3$

Tags: integers

Prove that the sum of a pair of twin primes, each greater than $3$, is divisible by $12$

I assume primes are $p$ ,$p+2$
Then their summation is $2(p+1)$
Since $p$ is prime, $p+1$ is divisible by $2$ .hence $2(p+1)$ is divisible by $4$.

Now again I have to show $2(p+1)$ is divisible by $3$ .then $2(p+1)$ will be divided by $12$.
But I am getting $p+1$ is divisible by $2$ always

Comment: All primes $>3$ are $\pm 1 \pmod 3$.  If $p\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ then $p+2$ would be divisible by $3$.  Therefore...

Comment: @lulu or even: All primes $>3$ are $\pm 1 \pmod 6$ so the sum of a twin prime pair (necessarily $6n-1$ and $6n+1$) is double a multiple of $6$

Comment: @Henry  True.  Though it's interesting, I think, to note that the lesser member of the pair must always be $-1\pmod 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $p$ is a prime number greater than $3$, so it can not be divisible by $3$. Hence, either we have $p=1 \;(\text{mod}\; 3)$ or $p=2 \;(\text{mod}\;\;3)$.

In the first case, we then have $p+2=0\;(\text{mod}\;\;3)$. Because $p+2$ also is prime, this is impossible.

Hence, we must have $p=2 \;(\text{mod}\;3)$. It follows that $p+1$ is divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 6):

Since $p$, $p+1$ and $p+2$ are three consecutive integers, one of them must be divisible by $3$.  You can rule out $p$ and $p+2$ since they are prime and they are not $3$.